# SFTP uploading file permission error and empty remote directory

Tags: sftp, docker

When connecting to sftp by `sftp user@serveripaddress`, I checked file list by `ls`, but this shows nothing in remote directory, also tried `cd` but no other paths I can move to.

I tried `lls`, this shows directory for my project.

tried to add directory in remote by, `mkdir test`
but gives me error:

```
Couldn't create directory: Permission denied
```

I have file found in local directory in `/backups/mall/20180524_mallproducts.csv`

So now I'm trying to test upload file to remote directory by command,
`put backups/client/mall/20180522150444_mallproduct.csv /`

this give me result of:

```
Uploading backups/client/mall/20180522150444_mallproduct.csv to /20180522150444_mallproduct.csv

remote open("/20180522150444_mallproduct.csv"): Permission denied
```

so I use chmod, but this gives me error, because remote directory is empty(no files or folders):

```
Couldn't setstat on "/": Permission denied
```

What could possibly be wrong? how can I change permission in sftp?

In `docker-compose.yml`, this is my setting for sftp,

```
sftp:
    image: atmoz/sftp
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ./data/sftp:/home/foo/upload
    ports:
        - "2222:22"
    command: sftp:pass:48
```

I was expecting folder `home` when accessing SFTP, but directory is empty.

At first I was accessing `sudo docker-compose exec sftp bash`,
It has `/home/foo/upload` directory to it.

But then I access by `sftp user@serveripaddress`, that is where I found out my code is trying to upload here.

This is the code for uploading via sftp:

```
<?php

namespace Mall\Infra\Transfer;

use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

class SftpPutTransfer
{

    /**
     * @var File $name
     */
    public function put(string $remote, string $local)
    {
        $sftp = new SFTP('user', 22);
        if (!$sftp->login('user', 'pass')) {
            var_dump('failed');
        } else {
            var_dump('success');
            var_dump($sftp->rawlist());
            $sftp->put($remote, $local, SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm confused on what SFTP to connect and test.

Answer (score 3):

According https://github.com/atmoz/sftp documentation, you must create at least one subdirectory and use it from there.